# Show image/animation above WKWebView

Tags: objective-c, animation, wkwebview

I would like to display an image as an animation that will just glance to the screen and then disappear after 1 or 2 seconds.
It should be  a layout above my already existing  WKWebView.
I was looking everywhere how to do it but couldn’t configure it out.

Thanks in  advance!

Answer (score 0):

In your viewController scene in storyboard, add a `UIImageView` on top of everything and attach your `IBOutlets` (or through code in `viewDidLoad`) and load your image. For example your `UIImageView *splashImageView`.

Then use this code in your `viewDidAppear` method:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f // this is a duration param
                        options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{
                         [self.splashImagaView setAlpha:0.0f];
                     } 
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     }];
```

For more details read [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2454/uiview-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-uiview-animation)

Hope this helps.